# Sum and product elements of vectors without using "sum"

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate sum and product elements of any vectors.

So, I wrote this code:

```
function [sum,product]=sum_pro(x)
product=1;
sum=0;
n=length(x);
 for i=1:n
     sum=sum+x[i];
     product=product*x[i];

 end




end
```

Unfortunately, I got:

> > sum_pro([1,2,3,4])
> >     Error: File: sum_pro.m Line: 6 Column: 15
> >     Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use
> >     parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the builitin functions [sum](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [prod](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html?searchHighlight=prod&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)?

Comment: I can't use sum and prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the error message, use parentheses when indexing, not square brackets:

```
function [my_sum,my_prod]=sum_pro(x)

my_prod=1;
my_sum=0;
n=length(x);
 for k=1:n
     my_sum=my_sum+x(k);
     my_prod=my_prod*x(k);

 end

end
```

Also, it's best practice to:

- not use `i` as a variable because is the imaginary number (`sqrt(-1)`) in MATLAB.
- not use `sum` and `prod` as variable names because they are MATLAB built-in functions

Comment: Thank You!. Now I have a new problem. Do you know why I got only sum : "sum_pro([1,2,3,4,5])

ans =

    15"

Comment: @PawełKusz Debug through your code, check the calculated values line by line and you can discover it yourself!

Comment: Because you didn't assign a return value when you call the function, so only the first return value is assigned to `ans`. Call your function this way: `[sumresult,prodresult]=sum_pro([1,2,3,4,5]) `

Comment: Might be better to replace the variables `sum` and `product` with `sumresult` and `prodresult`, respectively, so as not to mask built-in MATLAB functions [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [`prod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html). **Future visitors** trying out this code should be aware.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Thank you, good point. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @PawełKusz Please consider accepting my answer if it helped solve you problem. As mentioned, if you want two outputs to be returned when you call the function, you need to specify those explicitly.

Comment: @am304, it's a good answer and written to be accessible to both OP and future visitors.  (+1)